# Is it ok to have different decimal places when presenting different data in a paper?

Tags: formatting

I want to present my data with standard errors. The two might not be in the same order. Can I use different decimal places in one paragraph/paper like the below example? Or should I keep the same decimal places throughout?

> The production steadily increased from 3 ± 1 million metric tonnes
> (MT) in 2000 to 6 ± 0.4 MT in 2019, with rising net exportation
> from 0.2 ± 0.04 MT to 1 ± 0.1 MT  over the same period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb I learned about presenting measurements and standard deviations in the 1980s:

- give the standard deviation with 2 significant digits,
- give the mean with decimal places matching the deviation.

[ There might be exceptional, rare situations where you want to give the standard deviation with 3 or more digits, but that's only justified if you can really compute the standard deviation with such accuracy. ]

Examples:

- `5.83 ± 0.42`: okay
- `325.83 ± 0.42`: okay
- `325.8321 ± 0.0042`: okay
- `325000 ± 4200`: okay, two trailing zeros are there just to give the correct magnitude
- `5.80 ± 0.20`: okay, expressing that it's not e.g. `5.84 ± 0.16`
- `5.8 ± 0.2`: not okay, can be anything like e.g. `5.84 ± 0.16` or `5.75 ± 0.24` which makes quite a difference
- `6 ± 0.42`: not okay - if 6.00 is meant, that should be stated explicitly
- `5.831234567 ± 0.419876543`: not okay - you'll hardly ever be able to calculate a standard deviation up to 9 digits

Answer (score 3):

I don’t see much sense in giving the observables in a different precision than their confidence intervals:

- If you are giving a confidence interval, this is replacing the number of digits as an indicator of accuracy. Thus, you do not need to worry about the number of digits being misinterpreted.
- Your confidence intervals actually impose a higher accuracy. For example, take “1 ± 0.1”. Even in the most lenient interpretation, “1” can be anything between 0.95 and 1.5. That’s at least twice your confidence interval! Suppose I repeat your measurement and obtain 1.5 ± 0.1. This would agree with your result, if it is actually 1.4 ± 0.1, but considerably differ if yours is 1.0 ± 0.1. If your presentation doesn’t allow for this comparison, that’s pretty bad.

And just to avoid a misunderstanding: You do not need make different values of the same dimension have the same accuracy if the uncertainty doesn’t call for it. If you present one result as “37 ± 3” and another as “1.23 ± 0.15”, there is nothing wrong with that.

Sidenote: I would usually avoid giving an error as “± 0.1”, because there is a huge margin of inaccuracy in that presentation as well. It can be anything between 0.095 and 0.15, which can be a considerable difference. As a rule of thumb, I give the confidence interval with two significant digits if the first significant digit is 1 or 2, and one digit otherwise. I then give the value with as many digits as the confidence interval.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this looked a bit weird to me, and I had to think about it. I presume that your measurements do not support more decimal places. It would help if you mentioned this restriction. If you measurements support more decimal places, it would look better if you use the same number of decimal places in both. Of course, I was educated in Germany and customs there are a bit different than in the US. For example, I was taught that 5 is different from 5.0 because the latter shows the precision to which measurements were made.

Comment: Hi tschwarz, my measurements can support more decimal places. For instance, 6 ± 0.4 MT  actually is 5.8 ± 0.4 MT, or 5.83 ± 0.42 MT. But I just find the latter two are too detailed for the context of the paper, as the decimal part won't change the conclusion. Most readers would only be interested in the integer part, but I have to present the decimal part to show the precision of my measurement.

Comment: @Elizabeth For me, there is a large difference between "5.83 ± 0.42" and "6 ± 0.4". Even if you presume it's not interesting for your readers to know more than just the magnitude of the results, you should also think about other people referring to your work who want to know the data in more detail. Furthermore, it's about academic rigour.

Comment: I am not sure that being from Germany is relevant, but sure enough in a scientific context I read 5 as anything between 4.5 and 5.5 (extremes not included).
I dream the day that economy and the likes will be science, and not just some number to underpin arbitrary political choices (either in the communist or in the liberal world)

Comment: In the US, I have been criticized by co-authors when I write 10.0 instead of 10. In the German system, 10.0 means up to an accuracy of plus or minus 0.05.

Comment: In any case, I support the consensus. 5.8 pm 0.4 is correct (or using two digits).

Comment: Statistics is not different between Germany and the US. It is more likely that your US co-authors were ill-informed.

Comment: They are actually very well respected. They also tell me that the sign of multiplication is an x instead of a cdot. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No. Please be consisten throughout all your paper.

In [a comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/187084/is-it-ok-to-have-different-decimal-places-when-presenting-different-data-in-a-pa/187088#comment503988_187087) you state (emphasis is mine):

> For instance, **6 ± 0.4 MT actually is 5.8 ± 0.4** MT, or 5.83 ± 0.42 MT

Do not take it personally, this is horrible science. Please stop doing that. Science is already seen by the layman as another form of religion, doing thing with such poor rigour will just enforce that feeling.

Comment: got the point! thank you!

Comment: Consistency in the number of decimal places is not the issue. On the contrary! The number of decimal places should reflect the accuracy of the measurement. But I do agree with the rest of the answer: changing/manipulating values (even with the best of intentions) is horrible science - this cannot be emphasised enough.

Comment: may I ask a following question? if keeping the same decimal places, how many places should I keep? one or two, or three? are there any guidelines? if keeping one, there will be one or two cases like  0.2 ± 0.0 MT, if keeping two, I am still indecisive to change entire hundreds of data in the paper only to let one or two data be shown in full...

Comment: Can you elaborate why this is “horrible science”. (Not that I disagree, but right now the only thing substantiating your claims is that others agree with you.)

Comment: It is bad because 5.8 +/- 0.4 is not the same as 6 +/- 0.4. The first indicates a confidence interval between 5.4 and and 6.2, the second suggests a value between 5.6 and 6.4. A mean and confidence interval cannot be written down "in any way the author likes": it should be statistically correct, and the paper should also state what confidence intervals are used etc.

Comment: @Elizabeth have a look at here for a short sum-up 
https://web.lemoyne.edu/giunta/chm151L/scinot.html (Significant Figures: Addition and Subtraction) or here for a general description:

https://www.chemteam.info/SigFigs/SigFigRules.html

Comment: @Elizabeth "if keeping one, there will be one or two cases like 0.2 ± 0.0 MT" even not following correctly the significant figures rules, that already tells you that keeping one is very wrong.